# Cancel touchend if touchmove fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, touch-event, touchmove

I'm building something mainly for use on tablets, where the user can tap an item on the screen and a class is applied to it. This is what I have so far:

The problems:

1. I want to use touch events to remove the class and add the class on touch end (to make it faster).
2. I don't want it to do anything if the user swipes (touchmoves).

I've tried a number of things, none of which have worked. The simplest I've tried (unsuccessfully) is this:

```
var dragging = false;

$(".items").on("touchmove", function(){
      dragging = true;
});

$('.items').on("click touchend", function(event){
    if (dragging = true){
    }
    else{
    $('.items').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: `if (dragging = true)` should just be `if (dragging)`, or better yet `if (!dragging)` then move everything in the else statement into the if statement (therefore, you will have no else).

Comment: Once you `touchmove` once, you are setting `dragging = true`, this will a not allow any other clicks as per your code. You must reset `dragging = false` after the event finishes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**I would argue this is a more safe way of doing it**

Setting variable to false

```
var dragging = false;
```

Setting var to true ontouchmove (allows you to reuse this code everywhere in your app)

```
$("body").on("touchmove", function(){
  dragging = true;
});
```

Your button

```
$("#button").on("touchend", function(){
      if (dragging)
      return;

      // your button action code
});
```

Resetting variable (important)

```
$("body").on("touchstart", function(){
    dragging = false;
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You want to use either of the following:

```
if(dragging == true)
```

Or, simply:

```
if(dragging)
```

You should only use a single `=` sign when you are *setting* a value, whereas two `==` signs should be used when *checking* a value. Therefore, your code should look like:

```
$('.items').on("click touchend", function(event){
    if(!dragging)
    {
        $('.items').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Notice how you do not need to check if `dragging == true` because you are not running any code in this case. Instead you can simply check if `dragging == false` or, `!dragging`

Comment: for some reason it's not allowing me to add the 'select' class on touch devices, but it's working fine on desktop/laptop.

Comment: Here's a link to the full site: http://reveriesrefined.com/myftp/Crane/
the console isn't showing any errors in chrome or firefox.

Answer (score 2):

You can just check if event is cancelable. It's false after touchmove

```
$('.items').on("click touchend", function(event){
    if (event.cancelable){
        $('.items').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this is less complex than the accepted answer and it works. Thx

Answer (score 0):

where you have dragging check put

```
if (dragging == true){
   dragging = false;
}

else{
$('.items').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
}
```

it will reset it on release

also watch out for double calls on events as they sometimes trigger twice on some platforms best to check platform with first the following will help with checks

```
var clickEventType=((document.ontouchstart!==null)?'click':'touchend');
```

or

```
var clickEventType = 'touchend';
if(document.ontouchstart!==null)
{
     clickEventType = 'click';
}
```